# How to add Python libraries in locally created SAM Lambda app?

Tags: python, mongodb, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have created local SAM Lambda app on my machine and local MongoDB. My intention is to create a connection between SAM app and MongoDB. You can see the code:

```
import json
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/')
mydb = client['Employee']
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    information = mydb.employeeInformation
    record = {
        'FirstName' : 'Rehan',
        'LastName' : 'CH',
        'Department' : "IT" 
    }
    information.insert_one(record)
    print("Record added")
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(
            {
                "message": "Finally my local lambda worked.",
            
            }
        ),
    }
```

I have added the python library "PyMongo" using Pip install pymongo. But when I execute this SAM Lambda app, it throws an error that says:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'pymongo'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "d9a99323-2331-4228-s5f6-dd2e18d6a85e", "stackTrace": []}
```

Although, I have added the python library to the folder as you can see in the following picture:
[image]

Please tell me how to add libraries in the locally created SAM app.

I have added libraries on the AWS console but in the local environment, I don't know where to add these libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `pymongo` to the `requirements.txt` for each lambda function where you use the module.

It is not a standard module, nor the one preinstalled on lambda. You need to explicitly specify all such modules for SAM to include them into the lambda code.

No need to copy modules manually, let pip do the job. It will also take care of dependencies.

Comment: I have added PyMongo in the requirements.txt, now it throws almost similar error : {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': cannot import name 'pymongo' from 'pymongo' (/var/task/pymongo/__init__.py)", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "9ac2fbd3-8see-4cf1-ae40-65897f7ec38a", "stackTrace": []}

Comment: have you deleted the manually added pymongo?

Comment: I have deleted the previous one and created new Sam app, It is throwing the same error as you can see: {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'pymongo'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "c109a3a7-0b62-6a4a-9911-4e95658366757ff", "stackTrace": []}

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see what happens on your screen. It's pretty straightforward and should work out of the box. Could you confirm which OS you are using?  What commands do you run to reproduce the problem? List of files in the build directory? on linux host the build directory is in `.aws-sam/build/<function name>/` from the project root, where the template.yaml is located. Please add these details to the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, I am accepting your answer, and the new error was due to some other reasons. My pyMongo module is working now.